# Load dataframe from REST API in parallel

Tags: dask

I'd like to make parallel requests to a REST API via HTTP POST that returns CSV (optionally JSON) and load the results into a dataframe. Are there any examples for this situation? I've searched with no luck. Below is an example cURL command I can use to search:

```
    https://someserver/search \
    -d search="${1}" \
    -d count=100 -d output=csv
```

The search string would need to be different for each request to partition by some search predicate (like state="MD")

Answer (score 1):

This sounds pretty straight forward if you read through dask's `delayed` documentation

```
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas

url = 'https://someserver/search?search={}&count=100&output=csv'


@dask.delayed
def load_one_query(i):
    return pandas.read_csv(url.format(i))

df = dd.from_delayed([load_one_query(i) for i in ...])
```

(you might need to do URL quoting on your query/URL)

Comment: `return df.read_csv(url.format(i))` should say `return dd.read_csv(url.format(i))`. Unfortunately, I cannot edit the answer because of the stupid 6-letter minimum length requirement for edits...

Comment: Edited to what it should have been: it was a 6-character change :). Note that you should *not* call dask within the function that is being called by dask.

Comment: Yep, realized that after actually succeeding to run it but forgot to edit :D